# Send a data form to the parent component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a child component which contain a form and a parent component which contain the save button ! So I want to send the form in my child component to the parent component. The problem is that I don't have a submit button in my child component. So I don't know how to send this form.

My child component.ts :

```
 generalDataForm = new FormGroup({
occurenceDate: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
mainCause: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
ageBuilding: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
 })
```

My child component.html :

```
 <form class="k-form k-form-inline" style="padding-top:4px; " [formGroup]="generalDataForm" ">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 no-padding-left">
    <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
      <span style="font-size: small;">Date</span>
      <kendo-datepicker [max]="max" formControlName="occurenceDate" [format]="'dd/MM/y'"
        placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"></kendo-datepicker>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 10px;">
    <span style="font-size: small ;">age</span>
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 11px; padding-left: 15px;">
      <input type="radio" id="inftwoyears" value="inftwoyears" [formControlName]="'ageBuilding'"
        kendoRadioButton />
      <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="inftwoyears"
        style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">2</label>

      <input type="radio" id="suptwoyears" value="suptwoyears" [formControlName]="'ageBuilding'"
        kendoRadioButton />
      <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="suptwoyears"
        style="padding-left: 10px;">5</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 no-padding-left">
    <span>cause </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 no-padding-left">

    <kendo-combobox [data]="mainCauselist" class="form-control" formControlName="mainCause"
      >
    </kendo-combobox>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the parent component.html :

```
 <div class="" style="margin:0;">
          <app-generaldata-info></app-generaldata-info>
  </div>
  <button (click)="saveAndGoForUpload()" type="button"
        [disabled]=""
        class="btn">save</button>
```

the parent component.ts :

```
saveAndGoForUpload() { this.router.navigate(['dashboard/uploadFiles'])}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is after fill in all the form require, last input trigger on change to sent message to parent

parent component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <app-child (messageEvent)="receiveMessage($event)"></app-child>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent {

  constructor() { }

  message:string;

  receiveMessage($event) {
    this.message = $event
  }
}
```

child component

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
      <form ...
        on last child you may trigger
        <input type="text" (change)="toParent()" >
      </form>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {
   message = this.formBuilder.group({
      ...
    });
  @Output() messageEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  toParent() {
    this.messageEvent.emit(this.message)
  }
}
```

Comment: Here as I understand I will send only one part of my form not all the object form ! Can I changed like that `@Output() messageEvent = new EventEmitter<formGroup>();` to send all the form data ?

Comment: yes.. u can change that.. it depend on the data type u want to send.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) to access the data that your child component has at any time.

In your parent component declare a variable that gonna hold the reference of your child component. After that you can manipulate and access your child component from your parent
at any time.

**Parent TS**

```
@ViewChildren('child') childComponent: GeneraldataInfdComponent;
```

**Parent HTML**

```
 <app-generaldata-info #child></app-generaldata-info>
```

Comment: I used this solution and I add a console log in the save method of the parent component ` console.log(this.generalDataComponent.generalDataForm)` it gives me `undefined` in the console

Comment: Yes same happens

Comment: I don't know what you may do wrong, you can follow this article to understand more about content projection and access from parent view: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-viewchild-access-component

Comment: I have accessed components like that in a lot of projects, but as it is a sensitive thing, you may have to be careful with the reference and be sure that you have map the content correctly and when it is created.